# Test Internal Class Using Pax Exam

Tags: junit, osgi, osgi-bundle, pax-exam, pax-runner

Currently I have test class for testing internal class using Pax-Exam 5.

```
@ProbeBuilder
public TestProbeBuilder probeConfiguration(TestProbeBuilder probe) {
   probe.setHeader("Fragment-Host", "com.mycompany.abc");
   return probe;
}
```

The reason I use Fragment-Host is to avoid exporting internal package for bundle com.mycompany.abc.
But I get this error

```
org.ops4j.pax.exam.TestContainerException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid operation on a fragment.
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.install(NativeTestContainer.java:135)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.install(NativeTestContainer.java:140)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.installProbe(NativeTestContainer.java:428)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.setUp(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:68)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.beforeClass(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:106)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.ReactorManager.beforeClass(ReactorManager.java:400)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.DriverExtension.beforeClassBlock(DriverExtension.java:130)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.ExtensibleRunner$1.evaluate(ExtensibleRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Invalid operation on a fragment.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.checkFragment(Module.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:447)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.nat.internal.NativeTestContainer.install(NativeTestContainer.java:131)
... 15 more
```

Is there any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Fragments cannot be started as they do not have an independent lifecycle. The error is simply saying that you (or somebody) called the start method on a fragment. You need to find a way to configure PAX Exam to install but *not* start your fragment.

Comment: Hi @NeilBartlett, thank you for response. I am not able to find way to configure pax exam not to start bundle that contains the test class itself. Maybe you can help me by providing the link, please

Comment: Sorry I don't know either because I don't use PAX Exam. If I did know, I would have given this as a full-fledged answer to your question rather than just a comment. I hoped my comment would help you or somebody else to find the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pax Exam supports provisioning of fragments because you can call `.noStart()` on the provisioning Option to tell Pax Exam that the bundle/fragment must not be started:

```
CoreOptions.mavenBundle("gid", "aid", "version").noStart();
```

But what you are trying to achieve is different, you are trying to make your probe bundle into a fragment of the tested bundle.

You may still achieve your goal without having to make the probe a fragment as follows:

1. Use TinyBundles to create a fragment that exports the internal package(s) of the test bundle
2. Pass the fragment to Pax Exam as an url() option with .noStart()

see the following class for an example:

https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/blob/exam-reactor-3.2.0/itest/osgi/src/it/regression-multi/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/exam/regression/multi/fragment/FragmentTest.java#L61

In other words, rather than making the probe a fragment of the host, create on the fly an empty fragment just to export the packages of the host for the benefit of the probe.

Disclaimer: I did not try this, it's just an hypothesis.